# Loopback how to overwrite Role ACL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, loopback

How to open loopback build-in model Role only for admin? If I set "public":true in model-config.json then anyone can query Role methods.

```
"Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
```

I need only user with role "admin" to CRUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue.
in root.js

```
Promise.all([
    ACL.findOrCreate({
      model: Role.modelName,
      accessType: ACL.ALL,
      principalType: ACL.ROLE,
      principalId: '$everyone',
      permission: ACL.DENY,
      property: ACL.ALL
    })
    , ACL.findOrCreate({
      model: Role.modelName,
      accessType: ACL.ALL,
      principalType: ACL.ROLE,
      principalId: 'admin',
      permission: ACL.ALLOW,
      property: ACL.ALL
    })
  ]);
```